# Surrounding NativeScript events in brackets vs not?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I tried the following code`<Button text="hello?" tap="onTap"></Button>` as shown in a tutorial but the onTap function did not seem to execute.

The following code did work however. 
`<Button text="hello?" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>`
Is there something conventionally or otherwise wrong with the second block of code I have?

Comment: Have you followed any Angular tutorial before ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular event binding works either with parentheses such as:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Click me!</button>
```

Or in canonical form using the prefix -on such as:

```
<button on-click="onClick()">Click me!</button>
```

I believe you might be looking at the NativeScript Core Documentation and not the Angular one. Try looking at this: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-data-binding